Probability of a specific letters sequence
Let $\ X$ be the number of letters generated randomly until I encounter a specific three-letter sequence such as ABC. I want to find the expectancy of $\ X$.
I was thinking of just defining it as a geometric variable with a $\ p = \frac{1}{26^3} $ probability of success, and then the expectation would be $\ \frac{1}{p} $.
Not sure if I am missing something?

Your thinking is correct.

So no need to calculate the probability of each state separately? I am a little confused now

Even if I wanted to calculate the probability of “aaa” instead

To my regret, I have to retract my previous statement. The expected value is equal to $L^n$ only if the word does not contain identical subsequences at the beginning and end of the word (so called bifix). The proof can be found in the article of P. Nielsen (1973) who gives the simple formula for  the general case. Applying the formula to "aaa" gives the answer $26^3+26^2+26$.

Let us see how many letters are expected to be typed to generate ABC in sequence
Let X be the starting state when nothing useful has been typed
a be the state of having the last letter generated as A,
b be the state of having generated AB in sequence, and
c be the state of having generated ABC in sequence, then
proceeding step by step, we get
$X=1 + a/26 +25X/26 \tag1$
$a = 1 + a/26 + b/26 +24X/26 \tag 2$
$b = 1 +a/26  +24X/26 \tag 3$
Note that state c does not explicitly enter into the equations, the last equation expresses that if we do not revert to $X,\;or\; a$, we have reached $c$
Solving the set of linear equations, we get $X = \boxed{17576}$

@user: You are right, there was a slight error, I fed it to Wolfram now, have given link in answer.

Could you explain the addend $b/26$ in $(3)$?

@user: Inserted by mistake, corrected, thanks.

So, now it is indeed $26^3$.
